# EmEditorでマクロでマクロが動作するファイルを新規に出来たほうに切り替えるには何を書き足せば可能でしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

お世話になります。

EmEditorでテキストファイルの結合マクロを先に行ったあとに結合したファイルで続きのマクロを続行させるには、どのように記述すれば行けますでしょうか？

稼働の動画では、新しく結合ファイルが生成されて開いても、元の起点となったファイルそのものでマクロが続行されていますが、元のファイルはそのまま何も行われず、結合したファイルのほうでマクロの続行を切り替えて続行させたいです。

稼働の動画　この動画では元の結合前のファイルのほうでマクロが続行されてしまい新規の結合ファイルではマクロが動作していないです。
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDmRO42kcOQ

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

次のようにマクロを書いてください。

```
OldDoc = document;  // 古いドキュメントのオブジェクトを OldDoc に保存
// ここで新しい文書がアクティブになる (文書が切り替わる)
OldDoc.Activate();  // 古いドキュメントをアクティブにする
// 別のマクロを続行
```

**更新**

ファイルを結合した後、ファイルを読み直すだけでいいの場合は、ファイルを結合した後に、`editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4109);` を実行すればいいです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。こちらはどの部分に入れましたらいけますでしょうか？先頭や結合後の部分に入れても同様でした。もし、文書の切り替えに関する説明ページがありましたらアドレスをお願いいたします｡よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: お世話になっております。この切り替わりについては、EmEditorの仕様でしょうか？JavaScript側のもともとの仕様になりますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: あらためてマクロを見直していますが、ファイルを結合した後、ファイルを読み直せばいいのではないでしょうか? だとすると、私の回答は違っていて、ファイルを結合した後に、`editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4109);` を実行すればいいです。